# How can I add a dynamic class to an HTML tag?

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

For example, in the following example I want to add a class called "noDisplay" based on a certain condition. (1==1, for simplicity's sake.)

I tried:

```
<tr class='@if (1== 1) { Html.Raw("noDisplay"); }'>
```

And:

```
@if (1 == 1) { 
 @: class="noDisplay"
}>
```

Comment: Why are you trying to put code in a class name?

Comment: Not sure why this question was closed, but anyway. You cannot put logic inside the class attribute. Decide on class name earlier, store it in a variable and then use it in the class attribute. Aternatively you can render different tr tags in different if branches

Comment: @Andrei You can put logic there. For example, this works: `<div class="@if(true){<text>test</text>}">jkdfhwjkfh</div>`

Comment: @DavidG, ouch! Did not now that, thanks. In this case solutino might be as simple as just removing semicolon

Comment: @Andrei Notice that I said it was possible, not that it was a good idea! :)

Comment: @DavidG, absolutely, rendering code has no place in the attribute value. I am just trying to figure out why the code does not work.

Comment: @Andrei The code in the original question does work fine but the output from `Html.Raw` isn't passed back to Razor (it's just treated as logic. The solution is to prefix `Html.Raw` with @ like this: `@Html.Raw`

Comment: @DavidG, great. Would you mind posting an answer?

Answer (score 3):

What you posted is working but the `Html.Raw` section is just being treated as a function call, not as something to be rendered. The simple solution is to prefix the call with an `@` symbol (which will make Razor render the output of the function) or remove the call to `Html.Raw` and use `<text>` blocks:

```
<tr class='@if (1== 1) { @Html.Raw("noDisplay"); }'>
```

Or:

```
<tr class='@if (1== 1) { <text>noDisplay</text> }'>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to do:

```
@{
    var myClass = (1 == 1 ? "noDisplay" : "");
}

<tr class='@myClass'>
```

Or, just:

```
<tr class='@(1 == 1 ? "noDisplay" : "")'>
```

Comment: That's one solution. It can all be done inline, as well, like DavidG pointed out.

Comment: That's in the eye of the beholder, but your approach is definitely more portable... That is, you could reapply it on what I would assume to be multiple rows. Personally, I'd have the class as a property on my view model and take this logic out of the View entirely...

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a good idea to add the Class as a property to your ViewModel. The ViewModel should not know anything about how the data is represented in the View.

Comment: Yeah, that can be fuzzy, but I think in this case it's a matter of 'what' is being displayed, not 'how' it is being displayed.

Comment: By the way, I added the in-line version to my answer as well.

Comment: @ataravati: One could argue that the whole point of a view model is to fashion it for the view. I don't see a problem with the view model knowing how the view is going to use it, if that makes the code simpler and more maintainable. That's why we use view models instead of entities directly.

Comment: @ChrisPratt, I'm not strongly against having that information in a ViewModel. But, if you put that information in your ViewModel, every time you want to make a change to your CSS (change the class), you'll have to update the ViewModel and recompile the application. So, I prefer to avoid it unless it's necessary. And, in this case, I don't see it as a necessity. 

Anyway, the question doesn't have anything to do with using a ViewModel or not, and I think my solution is still much cleaner than the other answer.

Comment: Well, I was mostly playing Devil's advocate. I personally don't think it really matters one way or the other. I can see your point about requiring a rebuild, but on the other hand, ideally you shouldn't be changing classes around. That's the whole point of a css class: you define a generic functional class name, and then change the underlying style for that class, not the class itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
@{
    if(1 == 1)
    {
        var theClass = "noDisplay";
    }
}

<tr class='@theClass'>
```

The `@:` is an operator that outputs a single line of content containing plain text or unmatched HTML tags. The `@{ ... }` defines a block of code. Using `@` lets you access a variable that you may have defined in your code or other C# constructs.

Plenty more info and examples here: http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-razor-syntax-c